# Unknown $rootElementProvider: Qunit + angularjs integration

Tags: angularjs, qunit

When I try to inject $location service in unit test (qunit) I get error: 
**Unknown $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location**

Other things without $location service dependency are injected correctly.

```
 var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp']);
 var $location = $injector.get('$location');
```

source: http://jsfiddle.net/H4qGb/5/

One more strange error happens in the second test.

Does anybody know how to integrate angular with qunit best way?

Comment: I have this same problem using jasmine

Comment: Artem, have you found the answer to this problem?

Comment: No, I switched to jasmine. And now I realize that jasmine has much better integration with angular.

Comment: Your jsfiddle example doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 9):

You should be using the angularjs mocks.

http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular-mocks.js

You can then instruct your injector to also use these mocks.
`var $injector = angular.injector(['ngMock','ng', 'myApp']);`

http://jsfiddle.net/jxVDT/

Comment: Your JS Fiddle doesn't work, and the link just to the JS file isn't helpful in showing how to use it. Can you include an example usage for Jasmine in the answer itself?

Comment: When I load ngMock, I can't use $http anymore, it's mocked.