# Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location error in karma run

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

hi i am getting the error while running karma run

controller :

```
myApp.controller('LookupCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, LCService, $q, $http,$location) {....}
```

Here the above controller users LCService

LCService :

```
myApp.service("AccountService", function($rootScope, $http, $location) {...}
```

in karma.conf.js file

```
files: [
            //angular files
            'app/js/vendor/angular/angular.js',
            'app/js/vendor/angular/angular-route.js',
            ...

        ]
```

i have the 'angular-route.js' in my application as well., but when i run this it shows the following error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider<-$rootElement<-$location
```

how to fix this ?

Comment: related: [Unknown $rootElementProvider: Qunit + angularjs integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273373/unknown-rootelementprovider-qunit-angularjs-integration)